# What is the origin of h,l in format-specifier?

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

When I practice about C, I came to know "%hhd", "hd" format specifier.
It is easy to understanding, but I get about non-programing question.

I know about `<stdio>` is abbreviation of Standard Input/Output

So, I want to know the expansion of 'h' and 'l'.

It is silly question, but I want to know about this :)

Comment: Not really a C++ question

Comment: I think they just ran out of meaningful characters, and used what was available.

Comment: `l` has to be the first letter of `long`. For `h`, the first letter of `short` is already taken, so the second letter.

Comment: I always thought about them as "half". I hope someone can answer this in a reliable fashion.

Comment: @L.F. wow Thanks for your intelligence!! I'm enjoying like found origin of abbreviations :)

Comment: @anatolyg oh I also your inference sounds interesting! I thinks this is funny(Is it just for me?)

Comment: @JINU_K That's what first comes up in my mind and it's no more than a guess ;-)